# Phrases for filling stomach

Tags: phrases

"The food was so bad that I couldn't eat even just to (fill my stomach?)."

What would fit in there?

Comment: ... *satisfy my hunger*.

Comment: I'll make it an answer then.

Comment: The food was so bad that I’d rather starve to death than eat it.

Answer (score 4):

**Satisfy my hunger**.

The word *satisfy* is commonly used here, including [this definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/satisfy) from TheFreeDictionary:

> to put an end to (a desire, want, need, etc.) by sufficient or ample provision: to satisfy one's hunger.

Answer (score 2):

**fulfill my caloric content**

More technically accurate and not completely unrealistic to hear said in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**Sustenance**: something (such as food) that keeps someone or something alive.

"The food was so bad that I couldn't eat even for sustenance."

One could also use survive/survival.

"The food was so bad that I couldn't eat even just to survive."

Answer (score 0):

**sate** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sate)

> 1. To satisfy (an appetite) fully.

As in:

> The food was so bad that I couldn't eat even to just **sate** my
>   appetite.